# Is this Algorithm for lock-free fifo queue management any good?

Tags: delphi, lock-free, lazarus

I just found this:

http://www.emadar.com/fpc/lockfree.htm

at first glance it looks fine. Is anybody using it? Or maybe somebody already looked at it and found it unusable?

Comment: It looks OK to me. But be careful — it gives you no indication that you've exceeded the size of the queue if you add to many items. If the queue can hold 10 items and you add 11, the first item you read will be the last one you added, and it will also be the 11th one you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ok, it is only ok for x86 and x86_64 processors, and most likely not for PowerPC (and maybe ARM), since there are no memory barrier instructions.

I've it in production for a simple case, and noticed no problems. I use the non-generic one in Delphi though.

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance, it doesn't solve the [ABA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) problem.

Similar implementation that solves the ABA problem can be found [here](http://17slon.com/blogs/gabr/2008/07/working-lock-free-stack-implementation.html).

Comment: Perhaps it was implemented on LL/SC CPUs.